# app.less in not loading variables - Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using app.less to build the website but everytime i use variables that is in compiled bootstrap.css it says:

```
   12:19:57 C:\wamp\www\client\wp-content\themes\roots-master\assets\less\app.less  

    NameError: variable @white is undefined in C:\wamp\www\client\wp-content\themes\roots-master\assets\less\app.less:24:12
    23 color: #56c3f0;
    24 background: @white;
    25 }
```

In my compiler WinLess I have ticked app.less, bootstrap.less and bootstrap-responsive.less. What i need to do to have access to these variables ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is caused by changes in Bootstrap from version 2 to 3. According to [this page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342)

> Also removed @black and @white because #000 and #fff are 20% shorter and not something that should be controlled via variable.

Answer (score 0):

What according to your code I can see is you are using a variable in front of background tag. The code won't accept it. You have to use the color code or the image that you want to use in your background.
And if this is not the problem then explain properly that what the problem actually is?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i´m using an variable like you should use in LESS. The problem is in twitter boostrap the app.less don´t recon the variable that was set in other file.